# Problems uploading a ZK Face String Template to a device

Tags: c#, biometrics, zkteco

Device Model: SpeedFace-H5L
SDK Im using: StandAlone SDK-Ver6.3.1.34
Conected via TCP/IP

When i use GetUserFaceStr I get all the templates but when I try to do SetUserFaceStr the operation fails and returns a -103 Error Code, In the documentacion it says that this error means "-103 device send back error of face version error"

The Fp version code is

```
axCZKEM1.GetSysOption(GetMachineNumber(), "ZKFaceVersion", out strTemp);
```

Throws me a 58 Face Algorith

This is the code for getting and setting faces

```
public int sta_SetAllUserFaceInfo(ListBox lblOutputInfo, ProgressBar prgSta, ListView lvUserInfo)
{
    if (GetConnectState() == false)
    {
        lblOutputInfo.Items.Add("*Please connect first!");
        return -1024;
    }

    if (lvUserInfo.Items.Count == 0)
    {
        lblOutputInfo.Items.Add("*There is no data can upload!");
        return -1023;
    }

    string sEnrollNumber = "";
    string sEnabled = "";
    bool bEnabled = false;

    string sName = "";
    string sPassword = "";
    int iPrivilege = 0;
    string sTmpData = "";
    int iLength = 0;
    int iFaceIndex = 50;
    int num = 0;

    axCZKEM1.EnableDevice(iMachineNumber, false);
    for (int i = 0; i < lvUserInfo.Items.Count; i++)
    {
        sEnrollNumber = lvUserInfo.Items[i].SubItems[0].Text;
        sEnabled = lvUserInfo.Items[i].SubItems[1].Text;
        if (sEnabled == "true")
        {
            bEnabled = true;
        }
        else
        {
            bEnabled = false;
        }
        sName = lvUserInfo.Items[i].SubItems[2].Text;
        sPassword = lvUserInfo.Items[i].SubItems[3].Text;
        iPrivilege = Convert.ToInt32(lvUserInfo.Items[i].SubItems[4].Text);
        iLength = Convert.ToInt32(lvUserInfo.Items[i].SubItems[5].Text);
        sTmpData = lvUserInfo.Items[i].SubItems[6].Text;


        if (axCZKEM1.SSR_SetUserInfo(iMachineNumber, sEnrollNumber, sName, sPassword, iPrivilege, bEnabled))//upload user information to the device
        {
            if(axCZKEM1.SetUserFaceStr(iMachineNumber, sEnrollNumber, iFaceIndex, sTmpData, iLength)) //upload face templates information to the device
            {
                num++;
                prgSta.Value = num % 100;
            }
            else
            {
                axCZKEM1.GetLastError(ref idwErrorCode);
                lblOutputInfo.Items.Add("*Operation failed,ErrorCode=!" + idwErrorCode.ToString());
                axCZKEM1.EnableDevice(iMachineNumber, true);
            }
           
                
                
           
        }
        else
        {
            axCZKEM1.GetLastError(ref idwErrorCode);
            lblOutputInfo.Items.Add("*Operation failed,ErrorCode=!" + idwErrorCode.ToString());
            axCZKEM1.EnableDevice(iMachineNumber, true);
            return -1022;
        }
    }
    prgSta.Value = 100;

    axCZKEM1.RefreshData(iMachineNumber);//the data in the device should be refreshed
    axCZKEM1.EnableDevice(iMachineNumber, true);
    lblOutputInfo.Items.Add("Upload face successfully");
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: The SDKs are not fully compatible with visible light versions of the devices. Better try with web api

Answer (score 0):

It is a ZKteco error in SDK not compatible with device firmware. I faced same issue. It also happens with SpeedFace V4L